# Configuração gitlabCe no Docker

Tags: docker

Instalei o container do gilab no docker entretanto apareceram dois problemas:

1 - Se configurar a external_url o sistema não reinicia.
2 - Se olhar o caminho do projeto o SSH fica [git@x.x.x.x]:/caminhoDaPasta
Se for http fica http://7c38db0766c9/caminho da pasta.

Quais os parâmetros que devem ser alterados no arquivo .rb para sanar tais problemas.

Conteiner está sendo criado a partir do código abaixo:

```
docker run --detach \
    --publish 4430:443 --publish 8083:80 --publish 2222:22 \
    --name gitlabCe \
    --restart always \
    --volume $PWD/../src/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
    --volume $PWD/../src/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
    --volume $PWD/../src/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
    -e GITLAB_SIGNUP_ENABLED=false \
```

Sem modificações da imagem original.

As modificações que tentei realizar no external_url foi diretamente no arquivo .rb após o container estar em execução.

Comment: Você está alterando o .rb manualmente só para alterar a `external_url` ou está configurando a _env_ `GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG` do _container_? Está construindo alguma imagem a partir da `gitlab/gitlab-ce`? Como está criando o _container_? Bota mais informação aí do jeito que está aí é adivinhação

Comment: ola..estou alterando manualmente. usando a imagem original sem modificacao.